# Ubuntu after upgrade Network Hotspot full screen popup comes and goes

Tags: networking, 18.04, hot-spot

After upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04, facing some sort of weird things. This problem is recently occurring, where a window pops up out of nothing with title Network Hotspot and exits within a second.

[image: Hotspot login dialog]

I'm using an Asus Laptop with Intel Core i3 400 SL, 1.7GHz, 4GB Ram, 1TB HDD.

This doesn't seems to be hampering my Internet connection.

If any one knows how to fix this issue it would be helpful for me.

Comment: Is your WiFi connection stable? This happens to me when my router takes too long to restart a connection to the Internet. Ubuntu _thinks_ it is connected to a hotspot that requires a web login (Such as the one at airports or restaurants). The page disappears when Ubuntu finally sees that is already connected to the Internet. _The way that works, is that the OS connects to a preset non-HTTPS URL, in case of Gnome it is using http://nmcheck.gnome.org/check_network_status.txt. If it were a hotspot, the local router would automatically redirect to its login page._

Comment: Streaming video without any interrupt except this window coming in front of my video and goes in a second. And it's not showing one time it's coming randomly after some time.

Comment: I agree with @Dan: run a continuous `ping 1.1.1.1` in a terminal and look whether you have a disconnection there.  Video is buffered, so you won't notice a hiccup there...

Comment: Ok it's not coming while pinging and there is no drop on ping. But comes when not pinging. Still it's not a solution, need a permanent solution please.

Comment: @Fabby's comment wasn't a solution but more of a troubleshoot. Since you say there is no drop when pinging, I think the issue is on the router. On my router, I have an option which allows it to disconnect from the internet when idle, and reconnects to it after attempting to use it. Maybe you have the same option.

Comment: I agree with @Dan: It's a HotSpot issue, not an Ubuntu issue, so off-topic here but on-topic on our Android sister site [there](http://android.Stackexchange.com)...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This is an Android HotSpot issue and KeepAlive needs to be enabled on the phone.

Comment: @Dan can you explain more about your issue and what you did.

Comment: @Fabby all of sudden where did this android thing came from? Is that screenshot seems like android operating system to you? And why you vote to close as there is still no solution and answer found and I'm suffering this still.

Comment: **M.A.K.Ripon** Sorry, if your HotSpot is on an iPhone, you should go [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com) instead...  This is not an Ubuntu Issue but a HotSpot issue as the problem does not show itself when you're pinging the Internet constantly... **CC @Dan**, your input?

Comment: @Fabby I don't think it's an Android/iPhone issue, the "Hotspot login" is just the title that appears in the window in Ubuntu.

Comment: @Fabby sorry that you misunderstood the whole thing. I'm not using any hotspot mobile device for my internet. I'm just using simple tenda WiFi router where I'm using multiple devices and only this one causing this issue.

Comment: @M.A.K.Ripon All I did was just log in to my router and disable that feature completely. It wasn't an Ubuntu issue, it was an issue with my router.

Comment: @M.A.K.Ripon Regardless whether you use a WiFi on a router, a HotSpot on Android or a HotSpot on iOS, *the issue is external to Ubuntu* so you should change your router settings *not Ubuntu...* **0:-)**

Comment: @Fabby that's a great idea, if you can't change your wife behavior than change your wife, oh sorry WiFi :) . I'll try your idea thanks :)

Comment: @M.A.K.Ripon **:D ;-) :D Good one!** For commercial routers, [go here](https://superuser.com), another one of our sister sites, for and ISP-provided router, you should contact your ISP.

Comment: I'm running 3 device with Ubuntu under this ISP and only this device is acting it. Whatever, this question has already got 3 vote for closing and I waste my 50 rep on bounty here. Just a waste, not even got a little clue.

Comment: Experiencing the exact same issue on gigabit ethernet, never had any network issues before switching from unity to gnome.

Comment: This might works: 
https://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2018/03/disable-hotspot-login-on-ubuntu-1710-and-1804.html

Comment: I suddenly started to have this popup on Ubuntu 20.04 and never seen it before. Maybe it's time to reboot my router :)

Comment: It's crazy to consider this issue off-topic in Ubuntu section. It's something that bugs ubuntu users and that can be solved in ubuntu (see @holdfenytolvaj answer) or -probably- in the router, that you not necessarily can change.